# Add polygon (buffered line) created by turf.js to map in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, turf

I am trying to create a buffered line layer by creating GeoJSON line string from  routing line and buffering it with turf.js and then show it on the map.

Here is my code:

```
route.on('routeselected', function(e) {
    var r = e.route;
        var lineCoordinates = [],
            i,
            latLng;
        for (i = 0; i < r.coordinates.length; i++) {
            latLng = L.latLng(r.coordinates[i]);
            lineCoordinates.push([latLng.lng, latLng.lat]);
        }

        let lineString = L.polyline(lineCoordinates,{color: 'black'});
        var buffered = turf.buffer(lineString, 500, {units: 'miles'});
        var bufferedLayer = L.geoJSON(null);
        bufferedLayer.addData(buffered);
        bufferedLayer.addTo(map);
        });
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

`turf.buffer` method returns GeoJSON feature, which cannot be directly added to the map. You have to create GeoJSON layer, add feature to the layer and layer to the map. Leaflet polyline also has to be converted to GeoJSON to be used as input to `turf.buffer` method.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var buffered = turf.buffer(lineString.toGeoJSON(), 500, {units: 'miles'});
var bufferedLayer = L.geoJSON(null);
bufferedLayer.addData(buffered);
bufferedLayer.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion. I am getting "Uncaught Error: Unknown Geometry Type". Should i convert the array to geojson.If yes, then how?

Comment: I didn't test it, so I overlooked that Leaflet polyline has to be converted to GeoJSON for turf.js. See corrected answer.